# Can I create custom post type just for documents like PDF, Video, images? WordPress

Tags: wordpress

What I Have done until now, I am creating a WordPress plugin to add menu page for the document management in WordPress

```
<?php
/**
 *
 *
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name:       doc management
 */

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
     die;
}

/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'docs Management', 'manage_options', 'my_unique_identifier2', 'my_plugin_options','',4 );

}

/** Step 3. */
function my_plugin_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
        $file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'view/main.php';
    include_once $file;
}



?>
```

but I need to add functionality just like in WordPress Post and pages menu. So I am thinking instead of creating a new plugin for the functionality can I do it with custom post type. instead of adding pages or post I just want to add a document. that it's nothing else means instead of adding a new page. add a new document and list all those documents. bulk delete and all.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific need that you are trying to build a custom plugin?
I recommend, you may try using https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/